# Override JavaScript default parameter with undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a function with argument `bar` that has a default parameter, `""`. How do I override `bar`'s default parameter with value `undefined`?

```js
const foo = (bar = "") => {
  console.log(bar)
}

foo(null) // null
foo(undefined) // "" <-- I want this to log `undefined`
```

If this is impossible with default parameters, what would be an appropriate way to write `foo` to achieve this?

Comment: Is this purely academic or do you have a real-world use case for this?

Comment: In theory "[default function parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) allow named parameters to be initialized with default values if no value or *undefined* is passed"

Comment: @Phil real-world use case. the actual problem involves the formik library and mapping props to initial values for all inputs to `""`, except for certain fields such as dropdowns, where i need the initial value to be `undefined` because the dropdown value prop can only take `undefined` or an object type.

Comment: does it have to be console.log?  what is the code that uses the actual variable passed to the function?  can I see the source?

Comment: Can you please provide the real problem's sample code? https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/tutorial

Comment: Achieve what? If you'd just omit the default value it would work for the two cases in the code you posted. So in what case do you want to get the empty string?

Comment: @Bergi In most cases, I want it to default to the empty string. But in a couple special cases I want the internal `bar` argument inside `foo` to be of value `undefined`

Comment: @jchi2241 In most cases of `foo(undefined)`, or `foo()`, or something else? You could always pass a sentinel value, e.g. a known symbol.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> what would be an appropriate way to write `foo` to achieve this?

If you mean to default only when there is no parameter passed to the function call, then you need to check the `arguments` length, or to spread the arguments if you want to keep an arrow function.

```js
const foo = (...args) => {
  const bar = args.length ? args[0] : "";
  console.log(bar)
}

foo(null) // null
foo(undefined) // undefined
foo(); // ""
```

Comment: Great hack. However I'd like to note that if you find yourself needing to do something like this you need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 26):

### No, you can't, by design.

You've run into an interesting demonstration of JavaScript's 'two nulls', `null` and `undefined`.

`null` is **a designated null value**

`undefined` is **the absence of any value at all**

You ask about the passing the 'value' `undefined` but that premise is flawed. There *is no* value `undefined` - `undefined` is the lack of a value.

Therefore, you shouldn't pass `undefined` as a meaningful value to be interpreted by a function. I mean, you can, but from the point of view of JavaScript it is equivalent to passing *nothing at all* - so you're fighting against the design of the language and will run into issues like this one.

If you want to pass a meaningful, purposeful null value, that is what `null` is for.

Comment: Related: *[The Post JavaScript Apocalypse](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MBWAP_8zxaM&t=12m16s)* (at 12 min 16 secs)

Comment: -1 If JavaScript was perfectly sane, this _would_ be true, but it's not, and it's not. As @Kaiido's answer demonstrates, there absolutely is a difference between supplying `undefined` as an argument, and supplying no argument at all, specifically the length of `arguments`. Similarly there's a difference between objects that have a property where the "value" is `undefined` and where that property doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @Chris sure, but philosophically and pragmatically what I've said is true, and if you write your code around assumptions of `undefined` as a meaningful value you're going to run into issues and have to fight against the language. You can definitely use certain tricks to identify the presence of `undefined`, but at that point you're getting quite far into metaprogramming. In standard usage, for practical purposes, it's absolutely the case that `undefined` is functionally equivalent to the absence of a value.

Comment: Your objects example is an interesting one, by the way :-) But I'd actually say it's not a counter point to what I've said. Looking at the object as a mapping of keys to values, I think it's a legitimate usecase to actually want to have keys present (so you can, for instance, iterate over them) when you aren't sure yet what they map to. If you *know* they map to nothing, you assign them `null`, say, but when you don't know yet whether they'll map to something or not, you put them in the object but keep the value they're mapped to as `undefined` - i.e. the absence of a value

Comment: What you're saying is perfectly logical, and I would say is the correct way to program in JavaScript. It's just that if you don't know the difference, some bugs are going to kick your butt :-) I think my answer to the OP would have been, "Yes, you can do that, but you should code as if you couldn't."

Answer (score 15):

Maybe because you can't. That's the reason default parameters are designed to guard against `undefined` values.

As per Mozilla [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

> Default function parameters allow named parameters to be initialized
>   with default values if no value or undefined is passed

See above. It's clearly written: if `undefined` is passed, `default` parameters are used.

Answer (score 6):

**In the example code you just provided, that's apparently not possible**.

As per the [official documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters).

> In JavaScript, function parameters default to undefined. However, it's often useful to set a different default value. This is where default parameters can help.

Answer (score 3):

The very [definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) of default parameters is to initialize no values or *undefined* with the given values.

So, you would want to remove the default parameter and add a conditional check within your function(see Kaiido's answer). Otherwise, you cannot differentiate between foo(undefined) and foo().

If you want both foo(undefined) and foo() to log undefined, you can simply remove the default parameter

Answer (score 1):

Given this method (typescript, sorry I assume es6 is similar):

```
private static Foo(test: string, bar?: string): void
{
    let args = arguments && arguments.length ? arguments.length : 0;

    console.log(test, {
        bar: bar,
        type: typeof bar,
        isUndefined: bar === undefined,
        arguments: args,
        value: (bar === undefined && args == 2) ? undefined : (bar === null && args == 2) ? null : bar ? bar : ""
    });
}
```

Called with this:

```
let u;
let v = undefined;

this.Foo("no parameter");
this.Foo("null", null);
this.Foo("empty", "");
this.Foo("non-empty", "non-empty");
this.Foo("undefined", undefined);
this.Foo("undefined parameter", u);
this.Foo("parameter with value of undefined", v);
```

We get these results:

```
no parameter 
{bar: undefined, type: "undefined", isUndefined: true, arguments: 1, value: ""}

null 
{bar: null, type: "object", isUndefined: false, arguments: 2, value: null}

empty 
{bar: "", type: "string", isUndefined: false, arguments: 2, value: ""}

non-empty 
{bar: "non-empty", type: "string", isUndefined: false, arguments: 2, value: "non-empty"}

undefined 
{bar: undefined, type: "undefined", isUndefined: true, arguments: 2, value: undefined}

undefined parameter 
{bar: undefined, type: "undefined", isUndefined: true, arguments: 2, value: undefined}

parameter with value of undefined 
{bar: undefined, type: "undefined", isUndefined: true, arguments: 2, value: undefined}
```

Thus we can see that we cannot tell the difference between a variable that is undefined and a variable that contains the value undefined.

By looking at the number of arguments we can tell if an argument is missing, and then if it is exactly (===) undefined or null.

Comment: "*the difference between a variable that is undefined and a variable that contains the value undefined*" - uh, there is no such difference, that's why we cannot tell it :-)